# $\alpha$ Holder continuous function on $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $L(\alpha)$ be the set of $\alpha$ Holder continuous functions on the projective space $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ (Recall that a function $f:\mathbb{R}P^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $\alpha$ Holder continuous iff $f$ is continuous and $\sup_{x,y,x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d(x,y)^{\alpha}}<\infty$ where the distance $d(x,y)$ refers to the angle between the two lines $x$ and $y$). So my questions are: 
1. Are smooth functions (defined in the sense of manifold) inside $L(\alpha)$? 2. Why is $L(\alpha)$ dense in the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$? For the second question, i suspect we have to use Stone Weierstrass theorem but please  correct me if i am wrong.